# Can not see Wine's C drive

Tags: wine, files, directory

I have a problem. My Wine has a C drive, but it's invisible. When I try to locate it in terminal, I can see the path: /home/michal/.wine/drive_c/windows

Problem is, when I open my user directory "Michal", the /.wine/ directory is not visible. It's simply not there. How can I access it using Ubuntu's graphic interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice the '.' in front of the directory? On unix systems, the dot means the file is hidden. To view it in nautilus (the program used to view files in the gui, also known as "files"), go to your home directory and press "Ctrl+H". You will now see a whole bunch of "dot" files. Out of these, you will find .wine. The other dot files are used to store resources, settings and other stuff which you don't directly use (instead, a program you use uses the files).

Answer (score 2):

Directories starting with . is hidden. You can see hidden files and folders by pressing `ctrl+h`. And then hide them again by pressing `ctrl+h` again.